Updating organisation’s logo - copyright
If a non-profit organisation has a logo and then tasks a volunteer to update it, make it look more sleek, but essentially it’s a very similar logo, who is the owner of the updated logo?

Unlike a lot of design work... traditionally for logo work, all rights are transferred to the company/client upon completion and payment. So the company/client should own everything. Pricing should take in mind that all rights will be transferred upon completion.
The company/client needs to be free to use their logo as often and for anything they see fit. Restricting use, or retaining rights to a logo is often bad customer service (if not just greedy).
If it's is "very similar" and merely an "update", then the new logo may be simply derivative work - which intrinsically has little value for the designer. It can't be sold to anyone else if it's merely derivative, especially as a "logo".
